# javascript JS chart framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I want to draw chart like this image what is the best framework to do that and what is the type of this chart I don't think this is line chart?

[image]

I want a chart that can draw certain x and between 2 different y which chart can do that for me?

Comment: try d3.js, it is the best out there

Comment: Do you know what is the type of this char??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

This is a demo which is pretty similar to your chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/waterfall

Comment: I want something more specific for example I want to draw line in certain x but between 2 different y but I can't do that with this chart